# How to return any type of file from MVC action method?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, fileresult

I am saving the uploaded file content as byte array with file extension in database. I wanted to use file result which returns any type of file. How can i achieve it ?

I tried with image file. Can i do like below code for all types ? will that works ?

```
public ActionResult GetAttachmentById(int AttachmentId)
{
    try
    {
        byte[] AttachmentData = GetFromDatabase(AttachmentId);
        string FileExtension = GetExtensionFromDatabase(AttachmentId);
        return File(AttachmentData, FileExtension );
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return File("", FileExtension);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to define the Mimetype, file name and extension dynamically.

Then return a File object from the action like this:

```
string filename = "MyFile.txt"; // Make this dynamic from the actual file
byte[] filedata = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filepath);
string contentType = MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(filepath);

var contentDisposition = new System.Net.Mime.ContentDisposition
{
    FileName = filename,
    Inline = true
};
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", contentDisposition.ToString());

return File(filedata, contentType);
```